# Import repositories from TFVC to Git

Tags: git, migration, tfvc

I have some problems with importing repo from TFVC to git. I have follow this steps : https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/git/import-from-tfvc

But "Source Type" doesn't appear!

Screen :https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/git/_img/import-repo/importrepodialog.png

Comment: Go to code>Repo dropdown>import respository. then you should be prompt with a window you can select the source type there - TFS 2017

Comment: I have follow your steps but the window that is prompted does not contain "Source Type"

Comment: Could you share a screenshot of what you are prompt with in your anwser

Comment: get rid of your email in the screenshot, hmm thats strange what version of TFS are you using?

Comment: it's a google image, but it represents my same situation. I have tfs 2017

Comment: You can have a look at this you can do it through commands. https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs/blob/master/doc/usecases/migrate_tfs_to_git.md